# error InvalidAuthenticationToken (CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217) con el graph de microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, tokens

estoy desarrollando un proyecto ASP.Net en visual studio 2017. Para hacer las peticiones en nombre de un usuario obtengo a través de una petición POST el token de acceso y el de refresco.

La cuentión es que cuando paso la cadena del token a pelo (cuando la escribo directamente) entra sin problemas y todo funciona, pero al pasarlo a través de una variable falla.

```
 return new GraphServiceClient(

                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Variables.actoken);
                    }));

        }
```

La variable la he probado a declarar fuera y dentro, y siempre llega el token.
He probado también a comvertirla en secureString, pero da error también.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya sé lo que era. La petición estaba devolviendo el token más "\token". 
Lo que acababa construyendo un string del tipo "\"sdfhsyfdusfbhefbbgh"". Al abrir la variable en el visual me salía con las comillas nada más, creo que ese carácter se interpreta como salto de línea, ya que con el postman, en la respuesta el token aparecía una línea más abajo de lo normal.

Con la siguiente función lo solucioné:

```
public static string limpiarToken(string Token)
{
 string tokenb = Token.Substring(1);
            int tamaño = tokenb.Length - 1;
            string tokenf = tokenb.Substring(0, tamaño);
            return tokenf;
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.